# Python list dimension size error

Tags: python, list

Consider the following code in python:

```
def main():
    n = input( )
    s = input( )

    coins = [ 0 ]*n
    dp = [ 0 ]*( s+1 )

    print coins
    print dp

    for i in range( n ) :
        coins[ i ] = input( )

    dp[ 0 ]=0
    dp[ 1 ]=1

    for i in range( 2, s+1 ) :
        min_val = 999999
        for j in range( 0, n ) :
            if i-coins[ j ] > 0 :
                if dp[ i-coins[ j ] ] + 1 < min_val :
                    min_val = dp[ i-coins[ j ] ] + 1


    print coins
    print dp

    print coins[ s ]

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    main()
```

When I compile and run this program, I get the following runtime error:

```
File "test.py", line 33, in <module>
  main();
File "test.py", line 30 in main
  if dp[ i-coins[ j ] ] + 1 < min_val :

IndexError: list index out of range
```

What's wrong with it?

Input:

```
5 10
1 3 5 7 9
```

Comment: You do *not* need to use `;` semicolons in python. They only add noise.

Comment: Given that you've already used the expression `coins[j]` in the line above, that can't be it. Try printing the value of that expression.

Comment: Why are you importing `array`? You're not using any of the functions in that module.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I write basically in C++, so I have got used to add ;

Comment: I think you got confused about arrays as well then. In your code you are using python lists, which is fine, but don't call them arrays, nor do you need to import the `array` module.

Comment: The provided input results in `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'`, *not* an index exception. Did you initialize the arrays to `None` to try and deal with the IndexError you saw?

Comment: You don't "compile" a Python program.

Comment: @ecatmur: actually, you do, you just don't usually notice it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use

```
coins = [ 0 ]*n
dp = [ 0 ]*( s+1 )
```

to init the array.

I got an total different error on my machine:

```
  File "ttt.py", line 31, in <module>
    main()
  File "ttt.py", line 21, in main
    if dp[ i-coins[ j ] ] + 1 < min_val :
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

and `print dp[s]` rather than `print coins[s]` at the last line.

Answer (score 1):

We know (from the previous line `if`) that `i-coins[ j ] > 0`, so it must be greater than or equal to `len(dp)`, which is `s + 1`.  `i` is less than `s+1`, so `coins[ j ]` is a negative number.

Did you enter a negative number for one of the `coins`?

Answer (score 0):

dp is s+1 length but your for loop goes to n. If s+1 > n then this would work. But in this case I think your s+1 < n.

```
dp = [ None ]*( s+1 ); # dp is s+1 in length.

for j in range( 0, n ) # loop goes to n.
```

list index out of range means that s+1 < n